# JButton can't be disabled

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I have a JButton that I wish to disable when it has been pressed 10 times. Although, for some reason, my code doesn't work. Can you give me any help on this?

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    int counter = 0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        liste.add((double) Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
        textField.setText("");
        while(counter < 9)
        {
            counter++;

            if(counter == 10)
            {
                buton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I want to show a message dialog when it has been pressed 10 times. Can you help me?

Comment: You don't need the loop at all. Simply increment the counter when the button is pressed.

Comment: thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need the while loop, just move the `int counter = 0` above the `addActionListener(...`, and increment the counter inside the `public void actionPerformed()`. Then check `if (counter == 10)` inside the actionPerformed.

To show a message box, you use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog();`

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object))

> ```
> public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
>     Object message,
>     String title,
>     int messageType)
>     throws HeadlessException
> ```
>
> Brings up a dialog that displays a message using a default icon determined by the messageType parameter.

---

This is roughly what your code should end up looking like if you did it correctly.

```
int counter = 0;

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        counter++;

        if(counter == 10)
        {
            button.setEnabled(false);

            // Show message dialog
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is my message", "This is my message title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey. can you teach me how can i do addition-subtraction with arraylist?

Comment: @UğurHıdır Post a separate thread on Stack Overflow and link me to it, then I'll try to answer it the best I can.

Comment: @UğurHıdır If my answer helped you, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ) {
    if ( e.getClickCount() == 10 ) {
        ( (JButton) ev.getSource).setEnabled( false );
    }
}
```

or

```
int counter = 0;

private void functionForButtonClick (Events, handlers etc..){
    counter++;

    if(counter >= 10){
        btnHold1.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer is this. Thank you guys.

```
buton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  int counter = 0;
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
     liste.add((double) Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
     textField.setText("");
     counter++;
     if (counter == 10) {
        buton.setEnabled(false);
     }
   }
 }
```